# Как смонтировать usb modem?

Tags: linux, lxde, flash-память, модемы

Привет всем!

Такой вопрос: как смонтировать huawei modem для работы с флешкой microCD. фишка в том, что совсем не хочется ставить наутилус (он определяет модем автоматом), т.к. тянет слишком много библиотек за собой. Гном я удалил. Сижу на LXDE. А захламлять опять - неохота. Может есть возможность прописать какой-нибудь скриптик?

Заранее благодарен! :)

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе нужна только флешка то модем нужно перевести в режим только флешка. Уточни модель

На модеме нужно выполнить АТ команду

```
AT^U2DIAG=0 (девайс в режиме только модем)
AT^U2DIAG=1 (девайс в режиме модем + CD-ROM)
AT^U2DIAG=6 (девайс в режиме только сетевая карта)
```

Команду можно выполнить  с помощью `DC unlocker` или `Hyper Terminal` после этого он должен определятся как обычная флешка

Comment: следите, пожалуйста, за тэгами в вопросах, на которые вы отвечаете. Где вы возьмете `DC unlocker` или особенно `Hyper Terminal` под `linux`?

Comment: В своем ответе я указал как перевести модем в режим только флешка. В моем ответе предполагается что пользователь один раз переведет  модем в этот режим и дальше будет использовать его по Linux.  Не вижу смысла в Вашем минусе.

Answer (score -1):

Если карта микросиди в есть в модеме, она должна определятся как `sda`, `sdb` или подобное. Файловый менеджер у тебя скорее всего `pcmfm`, скорее всего отключена опция автомонтирования включи ее, если нет, `sudo mount /dev/название устройства /mnt/куда-либо`. Без микросиди (или флешки по простому) может определятся как сидирум (не всегад, но часто).